# Display remaining textbox characters C#

Tags: c#, textbox, character, max

I just wanted to know how to display the **remaining characters** in my textbox, just in case the user input exceeded the character limit.

For example, here is my textbox:

Enter Name: ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*___** *50 Characters remaining*

And when the user input is already 50 characters, he/she won't be able to type anything in that textbox anymore. Is that possible? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What UI technology are you using? WinForms? ASP.NET? MVC? Silverlight? WPF?

Comment: Isn't there a `TestBox.MaxLength` property? Displaying the remaining characters is just a bit of math.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you set the [MaxLength property of the textbox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength.aspx) to 50.
Then you need to subscribe to the `TextChanged` event of the textbox to be notified when the text of the box has changed, and calulate the remaining characters by subtracting `textBox.MaxLength` by `textBox.TextLength`

Answer (score 1):

You need `TextBox`'s `MaxLength` property.

You can achieve what you want by using a label on the right size of your text box.  On every key entered, you can update that label's caption to `$"{textbox1.MaxLength - textbox1.Text.Length()} characters"`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the textbox change event.

`labelForRemainingChars.Caption = txtMyTextBox.MaxLength - txtMyTextBox.TextLength;`

EDIT: This is applicable to winforms.

Comment: @Kristina: What GUI are you targetting? Winforms/WPF/ASP.net?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it's not clear but it looks like your putting the `Name:` part in the text box too, that should really go in a label. The same goes for the characters remaining.

As for calculating the remaining chars, use the `KeyPress` event of the textbox.

Your code for that event will be something like this

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var max = 100;
    label.Text = (max - this.Text) + " Characters remaining);
}
```

Hope this helps.